# What is $\sup_X \{ \inf_Y \{P(X > Y)\}\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, random-variables

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, such that $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$. What is $\sup_X \{ \inf_Y \{P(X > Y)\}\}$?

I managed to derive the following fact:

$\sup_X \{ \inf_Y \{P(X > Y)\}\} \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

One can get this simply by examining the case, when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d.

However, I failed to find any $X$ for which this bound is tight (i.e. such $X$, that $\forall Y$ $P(X > Y) \geq \frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: You don't have to find such $X$, because it's about the supremum, not the maximum. It suffices to find an $X$ for which $\inf_Y P(X > Y) \geq 0.5-\varepsilon$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @LinAlg, you are right. However, I do not know how to construct such $X$ either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually $0$.  Fix any $X$ with $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$, then there exists $N > 0$ such that $P(X > N) \le \varepsilon$.  Define $Y$ by $P(Y = N) = 1-\varepsilon$ and $P(Y = -K) = \varepsilon$, where $K = \frac{1-\varepsilon}{\varepsilon} N$ is chosen so that $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$.  Then
\begin{align*}
P(X > Y) = (1-\varepsilon)P(X > N) + \varepsilon P(X > -K) \le (1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon + \varepsilon \le 2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $\inf_Y P(X > Y) = 0$ and since $X$ was arbitrary we have $\sup_X \inf_Y P(X > Y) = 0$.